# Simplest WCF service to be consumed by C++

Tags: c#, c++, wcf

I'm a complete newbie regarding network stuff, but here are two scenarios I'd like to accomplish:

- I have a machine running a WCF service
- Scenario 1: on the same machine, I have a C++ app that needs to get data from that service
- Scenario 2: on a different machine, I have a C++ app that needs to get data from that service

The data that is exchanged will typically be around 1-10KB, but the method of transfer needs to also be able to handle bigger data exchanges (1-10MB).

What kind of configuration should I use on the WCF service to make this task as easy as possible?

Comment: Oh and by C++ I meant Unmanaged C++

Comment: It would be far simpler for you to use a mixed managed / unmanaged project, with the class that is interacting with the WCF service as a managed class

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I'd like 3rd parties to be able to write those C++ apps, and I'm not sure if they would be fine with managed code, or even if they would be using Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a service that can be accessed by non .NET code, the appropriate binding to use is [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx). This way you will generate a service that adheres to the standard published web service protocol.

If you are writing a client in unmanaged C++, calling a web service is supported by ATL.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k53kft2(VS.80).aspx for a walkthrough.